# How do I terminate/stop all other thread when I catch specific value in one of the thread execution (in activemq cpp)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I have parallely  launched 5 threads which are calling specific function. If one of them returns some specific value, I need to terminate the further processing of all other remaining threads and the specific function is called asynchronously in the *onMessage()* method.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `std::atomic<bool>& terminate_flag` to all launched threads. When one process find the searched for value, update the `terminate_flag`. All threads should be running an infinite loop? Modify the loop to exit when the `terminate_flag` gets set to `true`.

```
void thread_function(std::atomic<bool>& terminate_flag, T& search_value, ...)
{
    while(terminate_flag == false)
    {
        ...do stuff...
        if (found_value == search_value)
        {
            terminate_flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but even using this, thread_function will run atleast once in each thread right? @John

Comment: If one thread happens to find the value before a second thread gets to even start, then that second thread won't run. Well, it will *run*, but `terminate_flag` will be set to `true` and it will skip everything in the loop and then terminate.